# Error in Java: "missing Return statement"

Tags: java, return

I get the compilation error, `"missing return statement"` for this section of code. Not sure why? Also I know this is an inefficient way to write this so don't judge too hard :)

```
static int handValue(int card1, int card2){

   if((card1+card2)>=10)
     return 0;

   if((card1+card2)<=10)
     return card1+card2;

   if(card1>=10 && card2<=9 && card2>=1)
     return card2;

   if(card2>=10 && card1<=9 && card1>=1)
     return card1;

}
```

Comment: You need to return a value no matter what. So you could just add return -1 at the end.

Comment: The compiler does not know that you have if on all your possibilities. You have to return sth. if none off your conditions is true. A -1 would be good.

Comment: @Zhdawson, Did either of the answers below help? I notice you have asked 3 questions, received answers to them all, but [not actually marked any answers as accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A4610860+answers%3A1+hasaccepted%3Ano). If answers help you please consider [accepting the most helpful one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) using the check mark. This indicates to the wider community that it was a helpful answer and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

Answer (score 4):

The compiler is telling you that you don't have a `return` statement for all possible code paths. While that is not possible in your case, the compiler isn't built to figure that out: the path in question is the path where none of the `if` blocks get triggered by the values passed in for `card1` and `card2`.

In principle you just need to add a final `return` at the very end to prevent the warning.

```
static int handValue(int card1, int card2){
  if((card1+card2)>=10)
    return 0;   
  if((card1+card2)<=10)
    return card1+card2;    
  if(card1>=10 && card2<=9 && card2>=1)
    return card2;    
  if(card2>=10 && card1<=9 && card1>=1)
    return card1;
  return -1; // example return statement
}
```

You will need to pick an appropriate value to return. The alternative is to state that the method should always match one of those statements, then just add a `throw` statement for an `IllegalArgumentException` at the end of the method instead of the "default" return statement. As this is an unchecked exception callers don't have to follow the catch/specify principle.

However in the case of your code only the first two `if` statements are ever possible (the sum will always be either `>= 10` or `< 10` so you could just reduce this whole logic block; while I suspect you don't actually intend for this your method is actually equivalent to:

```
static int handValue(int card1, int card2){
  if((card1+card2)>=10)
    return 0;   
  else // if((card1+card2)<10) <---- note '<10' not '<=10' as in your original code
    return card1+card2;
}
```

or just

```
static int handValue(int card1, int card2) {
  return ((card1 + card2) >= 10) ? 0 : (card1 + card2);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

this will work:

```
static int handValue(int card1, int card2){
if((card1+card2)>=10)
  return 0;

if((card1+card2)<=10)
  return card1+card2;

if(card1>=10 && card2<=9 && card2>=1)
  return card2;

if(card2>=10 && card1<=9 && card1>=1)
  return card1;

 return -1;
}
```

if you define a return type you have to deliver one in each possible path of your method or you have to throw an exception like this:

```
static int handValue(int card1, int card2){
if((card1+card2)>=10)
  return 0;

if((card1+card2)<=10)
  return card1+card2;

if(card1>=10 && card2<=9 && card2>=1)
  return card2;

if(card2>=10 && card1<=9 && card1>=1)
  return card1;

 throw new RuntimeException("no cards!!!");
}
```

or

```
static int handValue(int card1, int card2)throws Exception{
if((card1+card2)>=10)
  return 0;

if((card1+card2)<=10)
  return card1+card2;

if(card1>=10 && card2<=9 && card2>=1)
  return card2;

if(card2>=10 && card1<=9 && card1>=1)
  return card1;

 throw new Exception("no cards!!!");
}
```

Comment: Then feel free to accept my answer. Click on the white hook at top left.

Answer (score 1):

The way you have written your function it is actually guaranteed to terminate on either the first or the second if statement because the sum of any two numbers is either greater than or equal to 10 or it's not. The Java compiler however is not smart enough to figure that out so it's telling you that you should have a return statement that is executed if all of the if statements fail.

In order to fix the error, and also make sure that your second two if statements can actually be reached I would rewrite the fuction as such :

```
  static int handValue(int card1, int card2) {
    if (card1 >= 10 && card2 <= 9 && card2 >= 1) {
      return card2;
    } else if (card2 >= 10 && card1 <= 9 && card1 >= 1) {
      return card1;
    } else if ((card1 + card2) <= 10) {
      return card1 + card2;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  }
```